# Handlebars link-to throwing error in ember-rails

Tags: ember.js, ember-rails

I'm using the ember-rails gem and following along with the starter screencast on the Emberjs.com site. When I create this link

```
 <li>{{#link-to 'about'}} About {{/link-to}}</li>
```

It's giving me this error

```
Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'link-to' on object <(generated application controller):ember280>.
```

There's a StackOverflow question that deals with this issue [Helpers not properly defined in application template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833027/helpers-not-properly-defined-in-application-template). One answer says that

> When you use Handlebars.compile it uses the handlebars script instead
>   of the Ember script. Ember has its own handlebars object that extends
>   the original Handlebars object with extra templates.

and gives this example

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{#linkTo 'dashboard'}}Dashboard{{/linkTo}}")
```

However, I'm unclear where to put that code, and would it need to be done for every link?

Comment: Maybe you're running an old version of the ember-rails gem, tried running `bundle update`? Or `rails generate ember:install --head` if you previously have pulled the latest builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running an older version of ember.  Try running this to get the latest version of Ember into your app.

```
rails generate ember:install --head
```